# How can I allow the replication user to execute 'COPY table TO STDOUT'?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to set up a logical replication between two postgre instances on my server (if that's relevant : the master would be a version `12.3` postgres, the slave a `13.1`).

I use a `replication` account on the master server, with `replication` grant.

After setting up a `publication` on master and a `subscription` on slave, I see error messages :

```
-- on master :
ERROR:  permission denied for table table1
STATEMENT:  COPY public.table1 TO STDOUT

-- on slave :
ERROR:  could not start initial contents copy for table "public.table1": ERROR:  permission denied for table table1
```

And indeed, using `psql` to connect to my database as `replication`, I see that `COPY table1 TO STDOUT` gets rejected.

**Question**

Is there a grant I should add to allow `COPY ... TO STDOUT` for the `replication` user ?
or is there something else I am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had overlooked a line in [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/logical-replication-security.html) :

> In order to be able to copy the initial table data, the role used for the replication connection must have the SELECT privilege on a published table (or be a superuser).

That would be :

```sql
-- while connected to the target database :
GRANT SELECT ON table1, table2, ... TO replication;

-- or, to grant access on all tables :
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO replication;
```